# WCF serializing response from JAX WS to an empty object - possible namespace issue?

Tags: wcf, jax-ws

I am using a WCF client to call a JAX web service.

When the response is deserialized, an array within the response object is always empty. However, if I mannually add the namespace to the array type within the response using a message inspector, the response is deserialized correctly.

So the response I get is:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:myResponse xmlns:ns2="http://mynamespace.com/">
      <myArray>
        <myObject>
          <myString>abcde</myString>
          <myInt>12345</myInt>
        </myObject>
      </myArray>
    <id>7777</id>
  </ns2:myResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

and this will produce an object of type myResponse, with the correct 'id' feild but an empty array of type myObject for the myArray field.

When I manually edit the recieved message to add the namespace alias 'ns2' before the myObject tags, so that it looks like this:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
  <S:Body>
    <ns2:myResponse xmlns:ns2="http://mynamespace.com/">
      <myArray>
        <ns2:myObject>
          <myString>abcde</myString>
          <myInt>12345</myInt>
        </ns2:myObject>
      </myArray>
    <id>7777</id>
  </ns2:myResponse>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

the correct object is deserialized ie with a myArray of size 1 containing the correct myObject.

Can anyone tell me why this is and how I can get the WCF deserialization to work correctly without manual intervention?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is exactly your problem, but may be worth a try.

We had a similar problem. In our case there was a complex object that was being deserialized with several fields missing. Using a debugger we could see that the information was there. But we could not get to it through the code.

What worked for us was to cast the object to a type that included all the fields.

Check your references.cs file, which datatypes are defined there?

Comment: Yes the type defined in reference.cs contains all of the nessesary fields. None of the fields are actually missing, i.e. nothing is null. The array field is of the correct type but it is empty when it should contain one item.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately it did not solve the problem.